# Proper relationship(s) of woocommerce tables in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filemaker

I'm using Filemaker pro to view and manage my Wordpress database and I'm trying to figure out the proper table relationship(s) for WooCommerce and other tables such as wp_posts. Does anyone have any experience with the mapping of which tables and fields?

For example, which woocommerce table and field would I map wp_post: ID to? etc...

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things in WordPress they are located in the tables;

posts AND postmeta

posts contain the single post and postmeta would contain all the posts fields and data, linked by post.id -> postmeta.post_id in a one to many relationship.

In the field posts.post_type you will see where things come from, a woocommerce product will have the "product" as content in the posts.post_type field.
That will be your link.

Hope this clears things for you...

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't. I know that information exists in post meta. What I'm trying to do is figure out the relationships of the woo tables - see - https://www.dropbox.com/s/35tm5hcyzip2qzf/Screenshot%202015-01-24%2012.01.09.png?dl=0 and also relate those back to the original post.